# Unable to set subscriber status via the PHP API

Tags: php

I am trying the code on this page
https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/managing_subscriber_status_for_one_or_all_lists/

```
$subscriber = new ExactTarget_Subscriber();    //If you create the new subscriber object . . .
$subscriber->EmailAddress = $email;            //. . . and specify the email address belonging to the subscriber . . .
$subscriber->SubscriberKey = $subscriberkey;   //. . . as well as the subscriber key of the subscriber . . .
$subscriber->Status = "Unsubscribed";          //. . . then you can specify a status of Unsubscribed (that subscriber won't receive messages sent to all lists in your account.
```

to update a subscriber status, but it does not seem to work. The code seems simple. Did I miss something? Has anyone had experience with this? I'd rather stay away from the Fuel SDK, because so far I'm using the native ET code structure. Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out, what an ordeal

Comment: Could you let us know? Currently having the same issue.

Comment: See my answer and PM me if you need more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out, this is what did it for me. Pretty simple actually and then you just need to pass the client object to the function after you've connected.

```
function reActivateSubscriber($client){
    $subscriber = new ExactTarget_Subscriber();
    $subscriber->Status = "Active";
    $sublist = new ExactTarget_SubscriberList();
    $sublist->ID = 1298; // specify listID, mine is for the master list.
    $sublist->Action = "update"; // specify what action to apply to subscriber on list (delete, update are other options)
    $sublist->Status = "Active";    
    }
```

To see it in context, check out my github repository
https://github.com/garek007/exacttarget-php-connect